# Regex to test if String have exactly two letters after hyphen (‐)?

Tags: c#

I want to check if string contains hyphen and exactly 2 letters after hyphen. If so, then it should return true else false. It should check from right side.
For example **THERMAX-BE** should return true while **BAJAJ-AUTO** should return false. Please Help.

Comment: `Regex.Match("THERMAX-BE","-[A-Z]{2}");`

Comment: by using `^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]{2}$` (you have to define your pattern in a better way e.g. 1 to n capital letters followed by a `-` and ending with 2 capital letters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could validate it by RegularExpression

```
bool Result = Regex.IsMatch("THERMAX-BE", "-[A-Z]{2}$");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a regex also:

```
var parts = myString.Split('-');
return parts.Last().Length == 2
```

However this won´t check if the characters are actual letters, even numbers or specific characters such as spaces or more hyphens would pass.

Comment: So what you're saying is that this is not an actual answer for the problem?

Comment: @Nasreddine Well, its *is* an answer to the OPs question, hoewver I won´t recommend this approach because it´s quite unstable.